# Use Global Variable $Setup in Lookup Filter

Tags: customsetting, lookup-filter, global-variables

Since global variables can not be used in Filter criteria, I created a formula field, to pass it through.
But referencing this formula (with global variable) in a Lookup Filter does not work

**Custom Setting: CompetitionSettings__c**

- Number: ***WinnerThreshhold__c***

**Custom Object: Participant__c**

- Number: Rank__c
- Formula: ***IsAWinner__c*** [Rank__c == ***$Setup.CompetitionSettings__c.WinnerThreshhold__c***]

This works so far and is displayed in the layouts. But as soon, as I try to reference this field in a filter criteria on a lookup, saving the criteria fails:

**Custom Object: Price__c**

- Lookup: AwardedTo__c

  Criteria: ***Participant__c.IsAWinner__c*** equals value TRUE

When I try to save this criteria, I get this Error message:

> Error: Error in referenced formula ***IsAWinner__c***, Field $Setup.CompetitionSettings__c.***WinnerThreshhold__c*** does not exist. Check spelling.

But it exists and it works in other contexts

---

Everything I found online is [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D94eAAC), where his statement at the end is:

> It looks like the actual problem is any $ formula fields referenced in a lookup filter...

But there is no reference for this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently that's not possible. The salesforce documentation on [Global Variables](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm) states that the $Setup variable is only available in `Visualforce pages`, `formula fields`, `validation rules`, `flow formulas` and `process formulas`.

Depending on what you want, there's a somewhat doable workaround [here](https://forcejay.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/lookup-filters-and-custom-settings/).

You can also vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kuTvAAI).

Comment: Thanks, this is a qualified answer. The workaround is not an option in my case, but at least I finally have the answer. Idea is upvoted. Thanks!

Comment: Quote from the workaround blog you just linked: "$setup fields aren’t available in the lookup filter selection and when they are referenced in formula fields the filter can’t be saved with an error stating that the $setup field cannot be found."